# Error when running multiple unit tests with a MySQL database connection in Laravel

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I've built some unit tests for a couple of my Laravel models. These are Eloquent models for items which need to be stored in a certain order, and as such, have methods to move the item up, down, and to defrag the ordering when an item is deleted. For this, I need to connect to a testing database (which I've done through a app/testing/database.php) and add some dummy data before I can test the methods.

Here's my **TestCase.php**:

```
<?php

class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $unitTesting = true;

        $testEnvironment = 'testing';

        return require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
    }

    public function prepareDatabaseForTests()
    {
            Artisan::call('migrate');
            Artisan::call('migrate:refresh');
            Artisan::call('db:seed');

            Mail::pretend(true);
    }
}
```

Then, running my first unit test works normally (**SectionTest.php**):

```
<?php

class SectionTest extends TestCase {

  public function setUp()
  {
    $this->prepareDatabaseForTests();
  }



  //Tests adding a new section
  public function testAddSection()
  {
    $this->assertTrue(true);
  }

}
```

As soon as I add my second set of tests, I get the error

> Fatal error: Class 'Artisan' not found in
>   /home/vagrant/Sites/mysite/app/tests/TestCase.php on line 26

Here's an example of my second test file (**CourseTest.php**):

```
<?php

class CourseTest extends TestCase {

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->prepareDatabaseForTests();

    }


  //Tests adding a new course
  public function testAddCourse()
  {
    $this->assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

When I remove the second test file (**CourseTest.php**), the phpunit test works normally. I've tried running `composer update` to make sure the autoloading is refreshed but still no luck. Can anyone suggest why this might be happening?

Comment: Me too got the error, including Facade didn`t work either

Answer (score 0):

Your migrate and reset orders are invalid. Try this.

```
public function setUp()
{
    Artisan::call('migrate');
    Artisan::call('db:seed');
}

public function teardown()
{
    Artisan::call('migrate:reset');
}
```

Check [this](http://snooptank.com/testing-with-database-in-laravel-4/) example.

**Note:** Touching database while doing unit tests is not a good habit. I suggest to use mocks in your unit tests.

Comment: I take your point about the DB and the mocks, however the fix isn't working. It's almost like the bootstrap isn't running. Any ideas? Many thanks for your help :)